# New Relic, Azure Web, c# Web API - no data

Tags: azure, newrelic

I have set up new relic in azure (Web Sites > My App > Configuration > Monitoring Tools > Custom) and I have also installed the NuGet package: **NewRelic.Azure.Websites**.
Then I changed my web config app settings to this:

```
<add key="NewRelic.AppName" value="My Website" />
```

and in the new relic config file, I changed this:

```
<application />
```

to this:

```
<application>
  <name>My Website</name>
</application>
```

I have disabled **Always On** and still I do not get any data.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to installing the 32bit through NuGet instead of the 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the Application Settings according to the [NewRelic documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/azure-web-apps)?

[image]

Remember that if you are using **ASPNet 5 /Core 1.0**, NewRelic is [not yet supported](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/asp-net-5-vnext/12589).